# Re-prompt credential box if username/pw is incorrect

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How do you Re-prompt credential box if username/pw is incorrect?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "Please enter Admin credential..."
$Creds = Get-Credential
```

My script runs everyline after even putting wrong username/pw (w error obvously)

I need `Get-Credential` to appear everytime the user/pass is invalid so I won't rerun the same script everytime I put in wrong information.

UPDATE:

Heres the sample script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "Please enter Admin credential..."
$Creds = Get-Credential
$Tpm = Get-wmiobject -ComputerName $wsid -Credential $Creds -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm -Class Win32_Tpm
```

I need to get the TPM of another computer and will require to enter user/pw to do the job. What I need is to validate if the user/name pw is correct and if not, reprompt the `Get-Credentials` screen.

Comment: This is because `Get-Credential` only takes the username and password. It doesn't verify the credentials.

Comment: It would be good if you can show where and how you  are using the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate credential with get-credential, instead you can use a try catch statement against the get-wmiobject, something like

```
$c=get-credential
try{
    gwmi -ComputerName comp1 -Credential $c -Class win32_bios
}
catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]{
    "wrong credential retry please"
    $c=get-credential
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test-Credentials() {
param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [PsCredential]$Creds
)

$IDX = 0   # Retry Limit Counter
$limit = 3 # Retry Limiter

$DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('domain')
while (!$DS.ValidateCredentials($Creds.UserName, $Creds.GetNetworkCredential().password) -and ($IDX -lt $limit)) {
    
    $IDX++
    
    Write-Host " - Failed - " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $Creds = Get-Credential -Message "Validaton Failed: Please Re-enter your credentials" -UserName $Creds.UserName
}
return $Creds
```